# JasperReports Server - Changing the calendar Javascript widget

Tags: javascript, jasperserver

I want to change the JasperReports Server 5's calendar widget in report parameters form to Jalali calendar (a completely different one from Gregorian).

I have the appropriate Javascript library to show the appropriate widget (don't worry about that), but I don't know where to put it and which file to change.
I've already tried:

- **optimized-scripts/report.viewer.page.js**
- **scripts/lib/dateFormatter-patched.js**

with no luck, any help is appreciated.